# Smith Wilson interpolation and extrapolation in SAS 9.1

Tags: sas, interpolation, finance, extrapolation

I want to make an algorithm in SAS that allows me to interpolate interest rates in SAS and extrapolate from the last interest rate towards an interest rate of 4.2% using the Smith-Wilson algoritm. The presented in this note: http://www.google.dk/url?url=http://www.finanstilsynet.no/Global/Forsikring%2520og%2520pensjon/Skadeforsikring/Tilsyn%2520og%2520overv%25C3%25A5king/Rapportering/A_Technical_Note_on_the_Smith-Wilson_Method_100701.pdf&rct=j&frm=1&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ei=9c3HU6vzCKjoywOw44Aw&ved=0CBMQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNFMmtifnZurgtIPcAukThrdBjIVnw

I was wondering if anyone have a code that does this? or knows if SAS has a build in function that will allow me to do this easily.

Any help would be great!

Best regards,
Mathias